# R Selecting only up to maxmimum

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean of all the acceleration values from a displacement value of 0.01 to max. However, I do not want to include any acceleration values after the maximum value. How is this done?

```
mean(
  subset(S1_Intns40_chainno-Sheet1,
    Displacement>0.01:max(Displacement),
    select=c("Acceleration"))$Acceleration)
[1] -0.8371687
```

Comment: Without a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your question is hard to answer because we cannot tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
limitedAvgAcc <- mean(data$Acceleration[(data$Displacement <= max)&(data$Displacement >= 0.01)])
```

This works because the bracketed statement create a Boolean vector, which is then used to subset the Acceleration vector, which is then averaged.

Comment: the OP also want the displacement to be >= 0.01. Otherwise, you've got the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I unfortunately get the following error. 


> limitedAvgAcc <- mean(`S1_Intns40_chainno-Sheet1`$Acceleration[(`S1_Intns40_chainno-Sheet1`$Displacement <= max)&(`S1_Intns40_chainno-Sheet1`$Displacement >= 0.01)])

Error in `S1_Intns40_chainno-Sheet1`$Displacement <= max : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types

@RichardErickson

Comment: @MarkusEsbjørnSloth, would you please provide an example of your data

Comment: Hmmmm... That should work. Could you post a small subset of the data to work with. Also, figure out what kind of data structure you're working with, and post that too.

Comment: Hope this can help. 

http://s14.postimg.org/4s46w56cx/data.png

http://s16.postimg.org/hdh0pj2rp/Rplot.png

Comment: Why are you stringing the variable name? And we still need to know in what way you are loading the data into its variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
lift_S1_intns40_chaino=
               (S1_Intns40_chainno[(which.min(S1_Intns40_chainno$Displacement<0.01)):
               (which.max(S1_Intns40_chainno$Dis)),])
```

I have gotten the following code to work well enough for my purpose.